# What is the active form of 'I must be scolded for my folly.'

Tags: active-voice, passive-voice

> I must be scolded for my folly.

Please kindly change into active. I changed it like this: is it correct?

> He must scold me for my folly.

Answer (score 4):

A passive voice sentence does not specify the agent - **who** is doing something - unless you add the agent using the preposition **by**. This is one of the main reasons for using passive voice- when you don't know, or it's not important to specify, who is the agent.

Given a passive voice sentence without an agent, it is not possible to convert it to active voice because the agent must become the subject of the active voice sentence.

> I must be scolded for my folly -> **[agent]** must scold me for my folly.

If you can fill in the agent, you will have an active voice version of the sentence.

Comment: What about "Someone must scold me for my folly?" I am not sure that it's identical in meaning to the passive form, but leaves the agent unknown, too. (On second thought, perhaps it would be more precise to say, "Someone ought to scold me for my folly.")